# Just started learning python in college for a password generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
import string

PassGen = ""
length = int(input("how many characters would you like your password to have 8-15? "))

while len(PassGen) != length:
Num1 = ['random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)']
Num2 = ['random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)']
Num3 = ['random.choice(string.digits)']
everything = [Num1, Num2, Num3]
PassGen += [random.choice(everything)]
if (PassGen) == length:
print (PassGen)
```

my problems are on the lines Num1, Num2, Num3 I have put single speech marks seemed to get it to work but I need to know if that's the correct way to fix it
furthermore for the line PassGen += [random.choice(everything)] I used on of the answers to change Everything to everything and still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. The code you posted doesn't seem to be Python...

Comment: It is python it’s python IDLE 3.4 I know that it is as it in a college

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that must be fixed for your script to work, as it appears you are trying to use coding conventions from another language...

1. Indentation is important in python, and logic and loops need indentation to follow them
2. Capitalization is important and variables are case sensitive. Typically only classes you define would have a capital first letter, or things like constants in the global scope (usually you protect your main code under a `if __name__ == "__main__":` block).
3. You seem to be using brackets to define lists inappropriately when you really only want a string
4. You seem to think `Num1 + Num2 + Num3` generates a list, since you then try to pick an item at random. However, lists are generated with `[]` (related to point 3).
5. You do not need to explicitly tell your loops to `Continue` and the keyword is `continue` (lowercase) in python anyways.

Here is a modified version of your script that should work (although I would personally code it with different conventions, I tried to change it as minimal as possible)

```
import random
import string

password_to_be_generated = ""
Length = int(input("how many characters would you like in you password"))

while len(password_to_be_generated) != Length:
    Num1 = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
    Num2 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    Num3 = random.choice(string.digits)
    Everything = [Num1, Num2, Num3]
    password_to_be_generated += random.choice(Everything)

print(password_to_be_generated)
```

I would recommend you review the basic syntax of python, as it seems pretty significantly different than what you are used to.

Comment: That seem like it might be it I’ll give it a go

Comment: tried it and it worked thanks a lot seems like I didnt need to edit my question

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the variable "Everything" with a capital E.
In your code, it has a lowercase "e".
Change this and it should work.

Comment: I’ll be sure to give it a try

Comment: Tryed that and it still saying the random isn’t defined

Comment: It will not work from simply changing E -> e. There are indentation errors also that will yield syntax errors. Also, OP has the `Num` variables as lists which will make the indexes incorrect as `random.choice(everything)` will yield a list instead of a string. Additionally, concatenation of strings cannot be done with lists like on the line `PassGen += [random.choice(everything)]` where OP tries to add a list to a string...Your answer does not mention any of these things.